# Ways to receive notifications in Microsoft Teams when tagged in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I want to set up an integration between Microsoft Teams and Azure Devops so that when someone is tagged in a work item in Devops, they receive a message in MS Teams about it. What is the most straightforward way to accomplish this?

I'm attempting to create a custom flow via PowerAutomate, but I'm not sure if this is possible (can't seem to find a parameter for mentions/tags to be the flow trigger). Am I missing something in PowerAutomate or is there another workaround / another tool to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Incoming Webhook you can send the adaptive card with user mention in Microsoft Teams.

Reference Document:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Service Hook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) in your Azure DevOps project. Use the Web Hooks service one.

With this one you can POST to a HTTP Url. This can be an Url from a When an HTTP request is received trigger action.

Jon Russell has created a nice blog about this approach:
https://www.jondoesflow.com/post/service-hooks-for-azure-devops-http-request-in-power-automate

[image]